# Clarification needed on how catch() works in a Promise chain with multiple .then() calls

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and need a clarification about using catch() in a Promise Chain. I have read multiple articles that simply state that a catch() at the end of a promise chain will handle an error from any of the .then() calls preceding it. I have also read that a .then(function(result)) will not be called if invoked on a rejected promise. So I can't understand how catch() at the end of a promise chain can catch an error without each .then() in between returning a rejected promise one after the another until it reached the .catch() part of it.

I wrote a piece of code that leads me to think that after an error is thrown from a .then(), each interim .then() then returns a rejected promise until it reaches the catch() part of the promise chain. I would like to know if I am getting this picture accurately.

```js
"use strict";

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("promise result");
})

// then1 holds a rejected promise
let then1 = promise.then(function(result) {
  alert("inside then1");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(new Error("hi error"));
  });
})

// The alert never displays so undertandably function(result) is not invoked
let then2 = then1.then(function(result) {
  alert("inside then2");
})

// then2.then() works leading me to believe then1.then() above did return a rejected promise
then2.then(function(result) {
  alert("inside then2_result");
  alert(result);
}, function(error) {
  alert("inside then2_error");
  alert(error);
});
```

Comment: The other thens are simply skipped until a catch is encountered.

Comment: If they are skipped then why then2.then() works? It works implying that then2 references a rejected promise.

Comment: The second argument to then2.then is what should happen on a rejected promise, so it's like a catch then

Comment: Correct, implying then2 is not empty as it should be if "then1.then(function(result)" was being skipped.

Comment: Why would it be empty? The execution of the handler is skipped because the promise is rejected, and the rejected promise is returned.

Comment: If `.then()` has no second argument, it simply passes along any rejections to the next `.then()` in the chain, and so on until you get to one with two arguments or `.catch()`

Comment: As Barmar and others said, the whole `.then(callback)` is not skipped, the calling of the passed in callback is skipped.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76325599/5217142)   (of mine) to "why does the Promises result looks like incorrect?" answers your question here.

Comment: "*without each .then() in between returning a rejected promise one after the another*" - well that's exactly what is happening. The promises are not "skipped", they **are** rejected one after the other, what is getting skipped is the execution of the `onFulfilled` callbacks.

Comment: Thank you all. Good to see I was in the ballpark of how it works in the background.